# Cant remove fireflies around emission object (volume scatter)

Tags: noise-reduction, denoise

Ive tried everything turning off caustics, ive turned on simplify, denoising is on, multiple importance is on, increased transparency, filter glossy all the way up to 10 (although there isnt glossy objects).

This is with denoising:

[image]

This is without:

[image]

Comment: How many samples are you using? However many you are using now, use more. Denoising is not always perfect, and is not a one size fits all tool for all scenes.

Comment: I was using 250 so o guess I'll go up to 500

Comment: Are you just trying to get the glare from the bright lightening? If so, how about a ‘fog’ glare node in the compositor? It would be much less noisy and far faster to render.

Comment: There's a volume scatter surrounding the trees and lightning so there would still be noise right I'd just be adding an effect on top to hide it

Comment: Yes - I was thinking *instead* of the volume scatter. If you wanted the trees to be infront of the 'glare' then you could render them on a separate layer and composite them together.

Comment: none of these solutions are working the glare solutions doesnt produce the result i envisioned

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve? Can you provide a sample image?

Comment: @AlexPensotti I posted an answer to your related auestion (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/120633/29586) - does this address your problem? If not, please clarify.